# Conditional Navigation Controller Root

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tab bar controller into a navigation controller. I want to change the navigation controller's root view depending on whether or not a user is logged in. How do I do this? I don't want to put the code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or any other AppDelegate method because it won't be the first thing the users will see.

Comment: See this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717260/iphone-replacing-rootview-in-navigation-controller][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717260/iphone-replacing-rootview-in-navigation-controller

Comment: In the first answer, I do not know what this array contains. `setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:detailViewController]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, its supposed to be:

```
- (void) goNext {
NextViewController* nextWindow = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextWindow] animated:YES];
}
```

Since you can't pop the root view controller, the following method can be used instead:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Here's a link to the 
[apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a) for this method.

Comment: So I put in the goNext code as this 
`NextViewController* nextWindow = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextWindow] animated:YES];`
since I am using storyboards and not Nibs, but when it changes ViewControllers, the screen is black. It doesn't have the buttons or any other UIElements I put in.

Comment: I found the problem. Since I am using Storyboards, this code worked for me. 
`- (void) goNext {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];

    NextViewController* nextWindow = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextView"];

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextWindow] animated:YES];
}`

Comment: cool, glad you got it to work. Yes, I should have mentioned that re-instantiating the controller is necessary when using storyboards.