# removeFromParentViewController doesnot update UINavigationbar

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

I want to remove all the viewcontrollers from UINavigationController. So I am using this code.

```
for (UIViewController* controller in navigationController.viewControllers) {
[controller removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

After that I create an new viewController and push it.

```
 UIViewController* newVC=[[UIViewController alloc] init]; 
 [navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Issue is all the viewcontrollers popout perfectly and adding newVC but on pushing newVC the navigationbar is getting a back button and title of newVC. On clicking back button it animates to the navigationbar of oldVC with title of oldVC that I have already removed in above loop;

Answer (score 0):

`removeFromParentViewController` is a `UIViewController` method, so it's normal it has nothing to do with `UINavigationBar`

In the case of a `UINavigationController` the `popViewControllerAnimated:` method handles the `removeFromParentViewController`part for you, along with navigation bar.

you can directly update the whole array of `viewControllers`of `UINavigationController`, calling `setViewControllers:animated:

see [Replacing rootView in navigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717260/iphone-replacing-rootview-in-navigation-controller)

Answer (score 0):

[navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newVC]];